# Add in functionality to tail logs while running script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a very short script.

```
    loading_animation &
    LOADING_ANIMATION=$!
    trap "kill -9 $LOADING_ANIMATION" `seq 0 15`
    task_to_be_performed
    echo "Script Complete"
```

Script it a little longer than this, but its sums it up nicely.

Is there a way to add in functionality so that if i press the key [L] while the script is running (animation being displayed) that the animation will stop, and it will start showing logs until task_to_be_performed is complete?

Basically, if i press [L], i want the animation to stop, `tail -f /var/log/messages` to start, and stop when task_to_be_performed is complete, then echoing "Script Complete" and exiting the script entirely.

I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
loading_animation &
ani_pid=$!
trap "kill -9 $ani_pid" 0
trap 'done=yes' USR1
output=ani
( task_to_be_performed; kill -USR1 $$) &
while true; do
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 input
    if [ ani = "$output" ] && [ l = "$input" ]; then
        output=log
        kill "$ani_pid"
        tail -f /var/log/messages &
        tail_pid=$!
        trap "kill -9 $tail_pid" 0
    fi
    if [ "$done" = yes ]; then
        kill -9 $tail_pid
        break
    fi
done
echo "Script Complete"
```

Comment: This works great as expected. I didn't think about using a timeout on the read command. Previously my look would get stuck on read, so i didn't think it was originally an option. Thanks!

Comment: @TrevorKS If this solves your question then you should accept the answer so that this question does not seem unanswered any more.

Comment: Sorry, i swear i did, but looks like it didn't update. Should be reflected now.